# Why my web app position is not fixed when build for mobile?

Tags: html, css, angular, cordova

I have web app build with Angular. I have tested with Web Developer responsive tool on a browser and works fine but giving a position issue when build for Android using Cordova.

But when I it moves when I use mouse like dragging (see the white space on right).

I have the following line in the `index.html`:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add to your body

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

maybe you can try

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

that's remove padding and margin for all node

Comment: Could you post your html body ?

Comment: That's all I have in the HTML body. Posted above.